# Redirection - url with get and white space

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect, url-rewriting

My boss asked me to redirect old urls to a new urls. But I can't do it for urls like this one:

```
RewriteRule search.php?rub=r24&mc=hello there  http://testv3.vintageandco.com/liste.chateau-mouton-rothschild.html [L,R=301]
```

I tried `Redirect permanent`, but it doesn't work.

Can someone help me please?

Think you (sorry for that English, it's not my native language).

Answer (score 1):

URL can't have whitespaces , use %20 instead

Comment: I did it but same problem. It works without & and ? is that normal ?